# How to change revision format in Google Code?

Tags: mercurial, google-code, changeset, hgrc

I'm REALLY new to DVCS and am trying out Mercurial with Google Code as I'd like to share some extensions that I recently wrote for Google Chrome.

I notice that in Google Code, most projects seem to refer to changesets via sequential numbers (eg. 1, 2, 3, etc. -- (see screenshot #1 below)). My test project (screenshot #2), however, uses the hex values and I don't see anything in project settings to change this. How do I get it to display using the aforementioned linear format?

---

Also, being new to social coding, it seems that everywhere else on the internet, your email address is a private thing but these DVC systems seem to want your email to associate with commits (and Google, github, etc. seem intent on displaying them). Is there some sort of etiquette here? It seems that most people on Google Code edit their config file to only show the username with no real name or email information for associated commits.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal because you're using mercurial. If you want sequential version numbers, you can switch to svn. Though, I think mercurial is far more superior.

Comment: In searching dozens of projects, I haven't seen a single project so far that doesn't have sequentially-numbered revisions. Are there really THAT many people still using SVN over Mercurial or Git? Also, any idea about the etiquette part?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/pure-lang/source/list ; Mercurial isn't very popular among Google Code users because GC is not very popular among Mercurial users.

Comment: SVN is very old compared to Mercurial or Git, so it has many more users. You should disclose you email, so other developers can contact you. However, I don't think that's a requirement.

Comment: Also, if you want to use mercurial, there are better sites to host code, such as bitbucket...

Comment: Thanks, both for the helpful insight!

Answer (score 0):

Dikei solved the mystory of the revision numbers -- let me answer your question about usernames. In a distributed system like Mercurial, a username such as "mg" would not be very useful and this is why it is normal to include the full name in changesets. Mercurial does not care, though, and you can put whatever you want there.